# Connect to mac address or UUID of raspberry pi from android device

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi, mac-address

I would like to connect to the MAC address of Raspberry Pi from  my Android device.

Is there any approach that i can follow in order to Connect to specific MAC address of Raspberry Pi.

Any suggestions are much appreciated .

Comment: given that Android OS now prohibits referring to MAC addresses it might be difficult at least from android OS..

Comment: @FredGrott, If possible could you please let me know,  How can i get possibly UUID address  from Android device

Comment: most telecom providers and other entities express horror at such things as someone transmitting un-encrypted UUIDs of an android device. and its frankly insecure..think about other optiions

Comment: I want to connect with UUID of Raspberry to android, i dont want to transmit UUID of android device